# Query nodes with a specific word in them

Tags: 7, database

I'm very new to Drupal and I need to grab all nodes that have a certain word in them, for example I want to grab all nodes with the Word 'Hello' inside the body field. I need to use the EntityFieldQuery class too. I'm assuming I need to use the fieldCondition method but not sure how to set that up as there's not a lot of documentation...

Thanks
Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I'd agree there's not a lot of documentation out there (there are *tons*, just search Google for *EntityFieldQuery*).

That said, something like:

```
$query = new EntityFieldQuery();
$query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
  ->propertyCondition('type', 'some_type')
  ->fieldCondition('body', 'value', '%' . db_like($input_string) . '%', 'LIKE');

$results = $query->execute();
```

is probably what you're looking for

Comment: Thanks, I agree there's lots of documentation but not enough code examples.

Comment: Good point actually, if it was clearer that EFQ wraps around a standard SelectQuery object it would probably be more obvious where to look for samples